# Localization in EnumDropDownListFor using asp.net boilerplate

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I have an enum dropdown

```
//control
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(
                        m => m.OrderBy,
                        new {@class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle toggle", onchange = "document.getElementById('hf_Pagename').value,this.form.submit();"})

//my enum
 public enum OrderByOptions
    {
        Default,
        PriceLowToHigh,
        PriceHighToLow,
        MostRecent
    }
```

Now the problem is I need to localize them. But in this case from" PriceLowToHigh" needs to change to " Price- low to high"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AbpDisplayNameAttribute`:

```
public enum OrderByOptions
{
    [AbpDisplayName(MyConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "OrderByOptions.Default")]
    Default,
    [AbpDisplayName(MyConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "OrderByOptions.PriceLowToHigh")]
    PriceLowToHigh,
    [AbpDisplayName(MyConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "OrderByOptions.PriceHighToLow")]
    PriceHighToLow,
    [AbpDisplayName(MyConsts.LocalizationSourceName, "OrderByOptions.MostRecent")]
    MostRecent
}
```

Define them in your localization files:

```
<text name="OrderByOptions.PriceLowToHigh">Price - Low to High</text>
```

**Update**

> AbpDisplayName works on type class

You can define:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class FieldAbpDisplayNameAttribute : AbpDisplayNameAttribute
{
    // ...
}
```

Then use `[FieldAbpDisplayNameAttribute(...)]` instead.

Comment: What should the `MyConsts.LocalizationSourceName` variable look like, given that you didn't add any extra localization sources? I can't find out what the default name should be

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve the issue.

**Way #1**
Don't use @Html.EnumDropDownListFor! Just traverse enum and create the html element like below;
*(I am writing the code on the top of my head)*

```
<select>
@foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(OrderByOptions)))
{
  <option value="@((int)item)">@(Localize(item.ToString()))</option>   
}
</select>
```

There's no Localize method. Just localize it with your way.

**Way #2**

Other alternative is not using enum but create a dropdown item collection. And let an item consist of DisplayText and Value. Display Text must be localized from server.

**Way #3**

Follow the instructions explained here:
https://ruijarimba.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/asp-net-mvc-creating-localized-dropdownlists-for-enums/

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant! Way easier (in our architecture at least) than setting up custom attributes that tie into the resources. Now we can use plain enums and localize them at the view level

Answer (score 0):

With the information above, I solve my problem this way.

I created a custome Attribute `AbpEnumDisplayNameAttribute` inherited from `AbpDisplayNameAttribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class AbpEnumDisplayNameAttribute : AbpDisplayNameAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="AbpDisplayNameAttribute"/> for enum values.
    /// </summary>
    public AbpEnumDisplayNameAttribute(string sourceName, string key) : base(sourceName, key)
    {
    }
}
```

Then I created an extension for Enum display value localization.

```
    public static class EnumLocalizationExtension
    {
        public static string ToLocalizedDisplayName(this Enum value)
        {
            var displayName = value.ToString();
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(displayName);
            if (fieldInfo != null)
            {
                var attribute = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AbpEnumDisplayNameAttribute), true)
                      .Cast<AbpEnumDisplayNameAttribute>().Single();

                if (attribute != null)
                {
                    displayName = attribute.DisplayName;
                }
            }
            return displayName;
        }
    }
```